# Using ArcGIS API interpolation functions (idw, kriging, splines) in my own dataset?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, interpolation, kriging, inverse-distance-weighted

Does ArcGIS API provide interpolation functions, like if I want to interpolate from my own set of values?

I know that ArcGIS provides functions for interpolation like IDW, Spline and Kriging etc, but can I use those functions to interpolate against my own dataset?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use them against your own code. Perhaps the easiest way is via arcpy, embedded within the [documentation for IDW](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009z0000006m000000.htm) you can see a stand-alone implementation of that particular function. Based on your previous question though, it sounds like you have a specific problem: you want to interpolate the values for a few unknown locations within an existing raster layer. If that is the case, then IDW and the like are not the right approach: they're intended for use against layers where you have a limited number of data points and want to interpolate the surface entirely.

For just filling a few holes, a simpler method would be to just perform a focal operation on the raster and replace any NoData cells with the average value of its surroundings. There's [another question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/5675/how-do-i-get-the-count-of-nodata-values-in-a-raster) which goes through the logic of using this method.

Answer (score 1):

IDW, Kriging etc is available with Spatial Analyst extension and not with the core product. You need to have a license of SA in order to use these functionalities out-of-the-box.