# Adding building and woodland heights to raster DTM using QGIS 2.18.19

Tags: qgis, raster-calculator

I am using QGIS 2.18.19 to produce viewsheds of a proposed development to show where the development would in theory be visible from. I am using Ordnance Survey Terrain 5 as my height data (*.asc) which I have loaded and saved out as a GeoTIFF so that it is correctly geo-referenced to the coordinate reference system I am using (OSGB36).

At present I have run a viewshed of the development using the DTM which gives the theoretical visibility as if the earth was bare.  I have a separate vector dataset of woodland which I have converted to a raster.

Firstly, how can I add give the woodland raster a notional height so that each block of woodland has a height of 10m?

Secondly, how do I add the raster of the woodland (with notional woodland height) to the DTM so that I have a raster of the DTM with woodland heights?

Comment: Not a duplicate, but it basically works like this: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/307648/107424. Just use your woodlands polygon instead.

Comment: Thanks - followed that tutorial through trying it using Raster - Conversion - Polygon to Raster and also using Rasterize (Vector to Raster) via processing toolbox and the Raster conversion way worked perfectly!!

Comment: @DavidG If you write that up as an answer to your own question it will help other people who come to this site.

Comment: Just a thought but have you had a look at what DTMs and DSMs if any are available from the EA for your area of interest? The DTMs are bare-earth models and the DSMs include surface vegetation and buildings. See:

https://ckan.publishing.service.gov.uk/publisher/environment-agency?q=dtm&sort=score+desc%2C+metadata_modified+desc and 

https://ckan.publishing.service.gov.uk/publisher/environment-agency?q=dsm&sort=score+desc%2C+metadata_modified+desc

Comment: Thanks - yes I have looked at the EA's DSMs although coverage is patchy in my area of interest

Answer (score 1):

As already said in comments, the question is different, but the solution is very similar to the one provided [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/307648/107424).

1. Add a height attribute to your woodlands vector layer.

[image]

2. Convert your woodlands layer to raster. (Using `SAGA Rasterize` tool here *as the QGIS2 tool is.. well, lets say outdated*). Make sure to choose your `heightattribute as Attribute` and `set the cellsize to your original DEMs cellsize`.

[image]

3. Run `r.null` on your just rasterized layer to `replace null values with 0`.

[image]

4. Use `Raster Calculator` to add the height to your original DEM. Use `"OriginalDEM@1" + "NullRaster@1"`

[image]

Comment: That's the process I followed.  The only slight difference was I did not need to use r.null to remove null values

Comment: @DavidG, consider accepting (and or upvoting it) the answer if it solved your Q. See: https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers. Tks.